# Capture images when the video is being played in the Android view

Tags: android, android-layout, video-capture, video-processing

I want to capture images when the video is being played in the android app. It will be great if anyone can please let me know the libraries for the application

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is capture the video and the do some sort of post-processing that splits the video file into the frames that you want.

There are a few libraries/tools available that enable you to do this in java.

- https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/
- http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/
- https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the links. I was talking about this only. I think the libraries are gonna be useful.